# How to run a cron on last day of the month on RHEL 7.2

Tags: cron, rhel7

How I can run a cronjob on the last day of the month in RHEL 7.2. Tried below methods. But didn't work. As of now for testing my script will just touch a file on one location. It's not working when I am using date function in a cronjob. But with normal crontab parameters, it is working.

```
52 23 28-31 * * ['$(/usr/bin/date +%d -d tomorrow)' == '01' ] && sh /apps/scripts/test.sh
52 23 * * * [ $(date +\%d) -eq $(echo $(cal) | awk '{print $NF}')] && /apps/scripts/test.sh
45 23 * * * [[ $(date +'%d') -eq $(cal | awk '!/^$/{ print $NF }' | tail -1) ]] && /apps/scripts/test.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct. However, there are a few syntax issues.

1. Cron has the nice feature that `%` marks the end of the command and the beginning of /dev/stdin for the corresponding command. So you have to escape it.
2. Your test command requires spaces after and before the brackets.
3. Single quotes will not do a command substitution

This boils down to:

```
52 23 * * * [ "$(date +\%d -d tomorrow)" = "01" ] && /apps/scripts/test.sh
```

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable
>          of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.
>
> **<sub>source: `man 5 crontab`</sub>**